# Why can I update a PostgreSQL column string but not an integer in Sequel from a JSONB value?

Tags: ruby, json, postgresql, sequel

I am using Sequel and I have a table with a JSONB hash as a column where I'd like to grab one of the values from that hash and store it all by itself in a table column. This is working for a string target column:

```
j = Sequel.pg_jsonb_op(:metadata)
DB[:litigation_cached_inputs].update(description: j.get_text('Summary'))
```

There my litigation_cached_inputs table is being updated to set the description string column to the value of the Summary hash key in the metadata JSONB column.

When I try to do the same thing, but where the target column's (`nature_of_suit`) type is integer (as opposed to here, where the `description` column is a string type), I get the error:

```
[42] pry(main)> DB[:litigation_cached_inputs].update(nature_of_suit: j.extract('NatureOfSuitID'))
2015-12-14T14:31:23-05:00 [DEBUG] 633 :   Sequel::Postgres::Database (3.3ms)  UPDATE "litigation_cached_inputs" SET "nature_of_suit" = jsonb_extract_path("metadata", 'NatureOfSuitID')
Sequel::DatabaseError: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "nature_of_suit" is of type integer but expression is of type jsonb
```

Why is this working when I want to extract a string, but not an integer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the value, and you can't cast `jsonb` directly to `integer`, you need an intermediate cast to `text`: `j.extract('NatureOfSuitID').cast(String).cast(Integer)`